# Angular UI Modal scope

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm having trouble with angular ui modal.

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: ModalInstanceCtrl,
      size: size,
      scope: $scope,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $scope.items;
        }
      }
    });
```

Here is the example: [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/MZzT2MdwjKPq5Pgo4wVK?p=preview) . The behavior of checkboxes is different. I think it is some kind of scope issue. How to make it works?

Comment: It's working for me. What's the problem?

Comment: The behavior of checkboxes is different.

Comment: How is it different?

Comment: Outside the modal they behave like radio buttons but inside they dont. I use the same functions in both ways.

Comment: You can remove scope:$scope and items: . And write  resolve: {
                    homeScope: function () {
                        return $scope;
                    }
                }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes here we got with the solution...

The scope is breaking inside the modal due to nesting of scopes.

Try using it by prototypical scope..

eg:

$scope.check.auto and $scope.check.notif
And when you set value for these variables in controller, they get reflected in both modal  and outside the modal...

Cheers

Comment: Can you provide code of your solution?I try to make something but can't make it work. Thank you.

Comment: updated plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/4OC4ELalMNQq3ht0voyT?p=preview  if this works for you then please vote up this answer